# VS Code + CMake : cmake.build not found

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-code

I have CMake working perfectly fine with Visual Studio 2015. I wanted to try VS Code with C++ and CMake extensions, but when I try to call the build command (configured to F7 by default with the CMake extension for VSCode), I only get the message:

```
command 'cmake.build' not found
```

Is it trying to tell me it can't find CMake ? Because Cmake is installed and working so... I also tried changing in the settings to the full path to cmake with no success. I installed both CMake and CMake Tools from Extensions. Also the toolbar for CMake doesn't appear on the blue VSCode toolbar as shown in CMake Tools extension doc.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issues, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @Dan see my answer :)

Comment: @jayphelps Thanks, that was it.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

The author of that extension believes they've resolved this issue in the latest version `0.9.7`.

https://github.com/vector-of-bool/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/157#issuecomment-307005140

> So, I've just pushed 0.9.7:
>
> 1. No more dependency on twxs.cmake, so that shouldn't be causing any
>      issues anymore
> 2. @ytimenkov fixed some version parsing code that was
>      lying about what version of CMake was installed. Should fix issues
>      people are seeing with pre-3.7 versions.
> 3. @ytimenkov added better
>      errors when initialization failed. This should help create future
>      tickets!
>
> As such, I'm going to close this issue and ask that anyone
>   with any further issues open a new ticket using the new error messages
>   that appear during a failed initialization.

---

I too had this issue and was given a [solution here in my ticket](https://github.com/vector-of-bool/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/157).

For some people, one of their dependencies isn't getting installed correctly on our system. So you need to install another additional extension to get it to work.

It's called "CMake" or "twxs.cmake" (actual package name) and can be found here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=twxs.cmake

If it still isn't working, some have reported that they needed to uninstall both extensions then reinstall them both to get it to work--making sure to restart VSCode.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do have both extensions already installed (CMake Tools and CMake)

Comment: @Kriegalex have you tried uninstalling them both and reinstalling, making sure you restart VSCode completely? Triple check you're installing the correct extension, since there are others with very similar names.

Comment: I just tried, same thing after, but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Kriegalex updated my answer, the issue should be resolved in version 0.9.7

Comment: I already created a new ticket with new 0.9.7 debug informations : vscode-cmake-tools/issues/170

Answer (score -1):

try this:

1. create a new copy of "mingw32-make.exe".
2. rename the copy to "make.exe".
3. restart your vscode.